# Python importing Module that does not exist?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, protocol-buffers, python-import

So I was running:

```
import google
> <module 'google' (built-in)>
```

In python prompt. 
    google.**path**

> ['/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google']

I want to delete the google module. So I :

```
rm -rf /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google
```

IT'S GONE!

But When I go back into python shell I get the same results as above.

(FYI, The python module was for protobuf I believe.)

Any ideas?

Comment: restart python console and see. A module is imported only once and any subsequent imports do not do anything.

Comment: ya done that. And restarted shell. I'll try computer? hah ** restarting computer didn't work hah

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this problem?

Comment: same results = you see 'Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google' again after checking google.__path__?

Comment: Google is doing strange stuff with [namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/) which results package name being decoupled from directory names somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to uninstall the 'protobuf' module.

```
sudo pip uninstall protobuf
```

Comment: This worked, but it doesn't make any sense...