# Python continues to install a module despite a pip uninstall

Tags: python, anaconda, site-packages

I used pip to uninstall the `google` python module. However, `import google` still works. What am I missing??  I want to banish this module from my computer

[image]

Comment: Have you restarted the shell after you did so? Because if not, there might be a cached `.pyc` or similar somewhere.

Comment: Restarted my computer.  No joy

Comment: After importing, just type `google` and post the output, as text would be best.

Comment: @Klaus D. `<module 'google' (built-in)>`

Comment: You are not the only one with that problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051654/python-importing-module-that-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the `repr` of `google` is `<module 'google' (built-in)>` implies that the module was baked into your interpreter; it can't be uninstalled, because it's been baked into Python itself (deleting it would involve carving out pieces of `python.exe` or `python*.dll`). Even C extension modules will reference their file if they were built separately (to a `.dll`/`.pyd` on Windows, to a `.so` on UNIX-likes); the fact that it doesn't provide the path to an existing file/folder means it's *really* built-in.

You see the same behavior in normal (non-Anaconda) Python installs with "critical" modules like `sys` which are considered so critical to normal Python functionality (e.g. implementing loading of modules) and/or always used so early in every Python program that it's not worth splitting them out for lazy loading.

It looks like the Anaconda folks baked `google` into the build for your distribution, they didn't just ship it "alongside". Point is, you can't uninstall it without replacing your Anaconda install with one that doesn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove this module then the easy way to remove it from anaconda-navigator. Open your dashboard and search for installed modules, from the list uncheck this module.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this too ..  Google module does not appear in the navigator either